# How to draw a polygon on the lower canvas background image using fabric js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a loaded image on canvas as a background image using fabric js. Since then the canvas element is splitted as two. Class name for these canvas element are,

1. lower-canvas - (uploaded background image)
2. upper-canvas - (Parent for the lower canvas)

When I try to draw something on the image that is being drawn on the upper-canvas only and unable to draw on the lower canvas.

Please find the image:

[image: Upper canvas]

I am able to draw only on this layer only. Unable to draw outside this.

Comment: You may want to start with that DOM tree, which shows that the upper canvas _is not at all_ the parent of the lower canvas. Both canvas elements sit side by side as independent bitmap graphics containers.

Comment: Thanks for your attention on this Halfer.
When you see my Html code

`<canvas id="c"  style="border:3px solid red"></canvas>`

have only one canvas element. At the time of DOM initialization the canvas is splitted as two.